# Function will print new lines, but won't output a variable result

Tags: c, function, variables

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isUpper(char*);
int causeUpper(char*);
int causeLower(char*);
int isNumber(char*);

int main(void)
{
    char userInput[1];
    int caseResult;
    int numResult;
    char newUpper;
    char newLower;

    printf("Input a character: ");
    scanf("%c", userInput);

    numResult = isNumber(userInput);

    if (numResult == 0)
    {
        caseResult = isUpper(userInput);
        if (caseResult == 0);
        {
            newUpper = causeUpper(userInput);
            printf("%c\n", newUpper);
        }//close of if statement

        if (caseResult == 1)
        {
            newLower = causeLower(userInput);
            printf("%c\n", newLower);
        }//close of if statement

    }//close of if statement

    if (numResult == 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", userInput);

    }//close of if statement

    if (userInput == ",")
    {
        exit;
    }//close of if statement

}//close of main function

int isUpper(char* userInput)
{
    if (*userInput > 64 && *userInput < 91)
    {
        return 1;
    }//close of if statement

    else
    {
        return 0;
    }//close of else statement

}//close of isUpper function

int causeUpper(char* userInput)
{
    *userInput = *userInput - 32;
    return *userInput;

}//close of causeUpper function

int causeLower(char* userInput)
{
    *userInput = *userInput + 32;
    return *userInput;

}//close of causeLower function

int isNumber(char* userInput)
{
    int numResult;

    if (*userInput >= '0' && *userInput <= '9')
    {
        numResult = 1;
        return numResult;

    }//close of if statement

    else
    {
        numResult = 0;
        return numResult;

    }//close of else statement

}//close of isNumber function
```

I made the suggested edits to my code and when I run it an input of 'a' turns into 'A', so that works, but when I try to test the next function an input of 'A' returns this instead of a lowercase letter:

```
 !
 A
```

How can I fix this error so that it only prints out a lowercase letter when I enter a capital letter?

Comment: Output newlines at the end of printing operations, not at the start.  You have a better chance of seeing what's going on if you do that.  Seeing `"\n%d"` gives me the heebie-jeebies; it should be `"%d\n"` or perhaps `"\n%d\n"` or even better `"Number: %d\n"`.

Comment: A condition like `if (*userInput > 47 && *userInput < 58)` should be `if (*userInput >= '0' && *userInput <= '9')`.  You could even use `if (isdigit((unsigned char)*userInput))` where `isdigit()` comes from `<ctype.h>`.  You probably shouldn't be passing a pointer to those functions either; you're not passing a string, and you're not modifying the data that the pointer points at, so there is no reason to pass a pointer.

Comment: `userInput = (userInput - 32);` --> `*userInput = *userInput - 32;`. (`userInput = (userInput + 32);`) same mistake. Also `scanf("%c", &userInput);` --> `scanf("%c", userInput);`

Comment: `printf("\n%d", userInput);` --> `printf("\n%c", *userInput);`

Comment: `if (caseResult == 0);` : Remove last `;`

Comment: Thanks to all! I was able to fix my code with the suggested edits.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You've got sharp eyes :p